# This is important. I need you to listen…

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story, cipher

Look, you don't know me. We've never met. But, like I said, I need you to listen...

I had the most disturbing dream the other night... Woke up in a cold sweat and couldn't get back to sleep. It wasn't a nightmare as such, just ... eerie, I guess? I don't even remember the details, but it left me with a real sense of foreboding. Weird thing about dreams, so clear when you have them, but the details fade so quickly... Vivid, yet fuzzy... And the strange logic that applies... Inconsistent flow of time... Disjointed cause and effect...

I'm rambling... The thing is, when I woke up, I found an odd magazine clipping on my bedside table. It feels so familiar, like I've had it for quite a while, but for some reason, I can't remember how or when I acquired it. Wherever it came from, all I know is that it I gives me the same creepy feeling my dream did.

Anyway, the strangest part about all this is... And perhaps you won't believe me... But, this piece of paper, I think...

...I think it's meant for *you*.

---

Here's a photo I took showing the whole page (click to enlarge):
[image: mysterious page]

I also took a [scan of the main picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7g38.png), but my intuition says it's the least important part. I thought the text of the main "article" might be more useful to you, so I've transcribed it here:

> **RXZMHTHXCUTANEMZNVNQDTH**
>   **MWDEJULDYHPHVERHBPGPOMT**
>
> pltdlgvqncltrr
>   umtmrqgba
>   mcdmwuygplpsdw
>   vaitzgifamqciw
>   wcogsplseplhbz
>   kgfibhsjyiebvt
>   jsurvclhzegko
>
> nipzsbwaetoivh
>   onbvrvhtslls
>   lusihvlncaawlttfv
>   bngamiivvc
>   dyktpklecfjbijm
>   lpuhhvqtneqtrw
>   wfsgtfvqkyshgk
>   ngtdwiivvlitga
>   nrhqmkcmrleflmgl
>   uwlmfwgvv
>   unayficwvhoickso
>   wfxjbklwfmsnf
>
> uwilt
>   RGMRI R VQKQ
>   LKH EOP A AGU A
>   kmuwzs
>   KNPW AGMR IIQ LBQP
>   KHAOP WFLZA WAK EZ
>
> qikbfvmaovsncb
>   qaoelayjrklvum
>   owgarzmmndm
>   brghwcovoyiflark
>   apsblpqiflmhjbty
>   fifmayvzpij

---

Hopefully this all means more to you than it does to me...

---

***Edit***: As per [this meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4530/etiquette-for-teaming-up-to-solve-a-puzzle), I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36672/this-is-important-i-need-you-to-listen) if people wish to collaborate and discuss theories or post their partial solutions/notes somewhere.

Comment: Incredible detail, all the little hints. Great puzzle!

Comment: Maybe this helps, but the text beneath the image seems to be in hex-format

Comment: @nine9: ...but the ad in the newspaper page seems to suggest the opposite... "Don't know ehere to start? NOT-HEX"... ;)

Comment: Hmm, for all those who haven't done so yet: **YOU DO WANT TO CLICK TO ENLARGE THE IMAGE**. ;c)  [Very mean, Alconja!]

Comment: wow, that scan is super high quality! it's like I'm looking at the original image!

Comment: Sheesh. This is a good one. Gunna have to dig in.

Comment: lazy-copy: 2F, 19A, 4E, 11D, 4A, 25C, 11A, 24A, 1B, 3F, 20C

Comment: @question_asker - I've... I've got a *very* high quality scanner...

Comment: Amazing puzzle!  This must have taken a lot of work to put together!  Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: This is such a well done puzzle, I wish I could spend rep to upvote it more than once

Comment: This puzzle is what led me to join Puzzling SE. Very nicely done!

Comment: @TNT - glad to hear it. Welcome. Make yourself at home. :)

Comment: *ad is in papyrus* I am never buying that product.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ - Glad someone noticed. It was a deliberate cheesy font choice to make for a generic advert. :)

Comment: @Alconja Ah, good to know! XD

Comment: I was reading through some of the answers wondering who is crazy enough to create such a riddle... well, why did I even ask :D

Comment: @Alconja How to do create images like that (https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7g38.png), if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: @noteness - no worries... you mean the static itself, or the method of hiding information?

Comment: @Alconja I get how to XOR images, but how do you make an image when XOR'd by itself upside down, turn to a meaningful image? What sorcery i this, lol

Comment: @noteness - first, you just need to make sure both your target image and the static have rotational symmetry. So, your static rotated diffs to all black, but then you take your target image, cut it in half, and invert pixels in the static that line up with that half image. Since you only inverted half the pixels, when rotated/diffed they now become white. Make sense? If not I can write up something longer when I get the chance...

Comment: Just perusing old puzzles and found this one... Holy smokes, Alconja! What an excellent puzzle... but I'm a little frightened...

Comment: @Alconja How did you create the image of the newspaper? O.o

Comment: @suomynonA - Just photoshop magic. Had a "flat" image layout of the content (i.e. everything but the paper). Tore up a piece of blank paper by eyeball to roughly the right size/shape and photographed it (got pretty lucky with the fit). Skewed the content to fit the paper and distorted slightly to account for the crumple (had to slightly warp the paper image itself to get the crossword to fit as I wanted it - you can see a slight bend in the wood grain in the lower right). Then just manually masked the content around the tear.

Comment: @Alconja Wow, nice work! Getting the paper the right size sounds very hard to do

Comment: Wow, by the way, you are the only person on Puzzling to get the Stellar Question (100 favorites) badge!

Answer (score 247, accepted):

(*Thanks to f'' for the help in chat! He solved the majority of this puzzle - I just came in at the end.*)

**Step 1: Crossword**

The crossword was solved by feelinferrety, Z. Dailey, and Sleafar:

> [image: crosswordsolved]

**Step 2: NOTHEX**

> In the caption, if you look at A and D only (as it says in the NOTHEX ad), and interpret them as crossword clues (only taking the letters not torn off) you get the message "THE TITLE IS THE KEY".

**Step 3: Using The Key**

> When you use the newspaper title as a Vignere key for the first paragraph, you get the message
>  "you're not listening read it again and realise the truth"
>
>  If you use the *question* title instead,

you get a message for all four paragraphs:

> well done you are
> beginning
> to see but we have
> not finished yet
> you need all your
> synapses firing
> for this to work
>
> a pirate's search
> but in reverse
> a map disguised here
> in the verse
> perfectly square
> this text aligns
> the mark is found
> follow the signs
> and now it dawns it's
> not enough
> dual maps required
> one fore one aft
>
> first
> ENEEE N SSWW
> SWW WWW W NNN S
> second
> WWWW NNEE EEN NNWW
> WWSWW SSSSS ESS WN
>
> but if it's broken
> what difference
> would it make
> once you can answer
> that the truth will
> become clear

**Step 4: Following Directions**

> "In the verse / perfectly square" hints at the poems being more than just instructions. In fact, all of the text in the "article" is exactly 400 letters, which can be arranged into a 20×20 grid. "A pirate's search but in reverse" hints that we're starting at an X instead of ending at one. So, if you take the text and arrange it into a square grid, you get this:
> `pltdlgvqncltrrumtmrq`
> `gbamcdmwuygplpsdwvai`
> `tzgifamqciwwcogsplse`
> `plhbzkgfibhsjyiebvtj`
> `survclhzegkonipzsbwa`
> `etoivhonbvrvhtsllslu`
> `sihvlncaawlttfvbngam`
> `iivvcdyktpklecfjbijm`
> `lpuhhvqtneqtrwwfsgtf`
> `vqkyshgkngtdwiivvlit`
> `ganrhqmkcmrleflmgluw`
> `lmfwgvvunayficwvhoic`
> `ksowfXjbklwfmsnfuwil`
> `trgmrirvqkqlkheopaag`
> `uakmuwzsknpwagmriiql`
> `bqpkhaopwflzawakezqi`
> `kbfvmaovsncbqaoelayj`
> `rklvumowgarzmmndmbrg`
> `hwcovoyiflarkapsblpq`
> `iflmhjbtyfifmayvzpij`
> **and for the plaintext:**
> `welldoneyouarebeginn`
> `ingtoseebutwehavenot`
> `finishedyetyouneedal`
> `lyoursynapsesfiringf`
> `orthistoworkapirates`
> `searchbutinreverseam`
> `apdisguisedhereinthe`
> `verseperfectlysquare`
> `thisteXtalignsthemar`
> `kisfoundfollowthesig`
> `nsandnowitdawnsitsno`
> `tenoughdualmapsrequi`
> `redoneforeoneaftfirs`
> `teneeensswwswwwwwwnn`
> `nssecondwwwwnneeeenn`
> `nwwwwswwsssssesswnbu`
> `tifitsbrokenwhatdiff`
> `erencewoulditmakeonc`
> `eyoucananswerthatthe`
> `truthwillbecomeclear`
>  Follow the directions in the third paragraph on the first grid (taking letters after every space), and you get the message "AMBIGRAM". If you repeat the process with the second grid and the second set of directions ("dual maps required, one fore one aft") you get "ISBROKEN".

**Step 5: The Image**

> An ambigram is the same thing upside-down and right-side-up. The image is *almost* an ambigram, but some pixels are changed. If you XOR the image with itself rotated 180°, you get the following: [image: pleasewakeup]

**Step 6: Interpreting Everything**

> Well, we appear to be in a coma. The messages on the borders of the "please wake up!" image are:
>  - We've been trying to get a message to you...
>  - You're in a coma...
>  - There was an accident...
>  - Open your eyes...
>  - We miss you...
>
> Even the crossword clues hint that you're in a coma: specifically, the unused clues for 7, 16, 21, and 26 across. (The solutions to those are "accident", "pity", "coma", and "dream".)
>
>  So we have two options: waking up and having to talk to people or staying in weird coma-land where everything is puzzles. I know which one *I'd* choose.

Comment: what an amazing and chilling puzzle!

Comment: Chilling. Brilliant. Well done!

Comment: Amazing answer, and honestly this is an even more amazing puzzle. Congratulations man !

Comment: Dayuuuuum. Brilliant.  Absolutely brilliant.

Comment: What if I am actually in a coma and this riddle I see in my dreams is a hint from the real world... oO

Comment: @dounyy OPEN YOUR EYES :p

Comment: How did you find "The Title Is The Key"? How did you use A & D to find that

Comment: @DevilApple227: A is "Across", D is "Down". Take the clues hinted at, ignoring other letters.

Comment: @Deusovi Can you describe the image and the XOR process?  How did you convert the image from parallelogram to simple digital content?  Presumably a rectangular GIF or just raw matrix 8 bit black and white content?

Comment: @zipzit: Alconja provided a 'scan' of the actual image just under the image in the post. I just used that, duplicated the layer on Paint.NET, flipped one layer over, then combined with XOR.

Comment: @Deusovi Whoa!  I'm a big user of paint.net and never realized that layer --> properties --> blending --> mode option was there.  In fact, a majority of those blend mode options will result in revealing the hidden messages.  many thanks for that help.  And I was thinking you used OpenCV or Matlab.

Comment: @zipzit - re: the majority of blend modes working, you're right, and in fact the text ("but, if it's broken, what difference would it make?") was intended to hint towards taking the mathematical difference of the pixel data (I.e. difference blend mode, not xor).

Comment: @Alconja: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. I just used xor because it would make all the "correct" pixels one color.

Comment: @Deusovi can you provide me the link for paint.net?

Comment: @user66: getpaint.net

Comment: I had goosebumps all over when I read the solution. Wow!

Comment: How did you get the image part of XOR the image with itself rotated 180 degree??

Comment: @wrangler That's just an easy way to check which pixels are the same as their opposites. It's not a step in the puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi can you explain me that sentence: 'If you use the question title instead'?
I can not understand what is it the key! I am becoming crazy.

Comment: @SteeBono Use the question title as a Vigenere key for the newspaper article text.

Comment: @Deusovi Ok, but I do not understand what is it the 'question title'. Can you give me the key? I have tried with title of stackexchange question but do not works

Comment: @SteeBono Yes, the key is "This is important...". The message to decode is the *text* of the newspaper article, not the title: starting "pltdl..." Paste both of those in [here](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/vigenere.php) and choose "decrypt".

Comment: @Deusovi I had tried the question title key on another website to decrypt the text of newspaper and it did not work. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Deusovi but how did you know to use a Vignere key??

Comment: @temporary_user_name Vigenère is the most well-known keyed cipher by far.

Answer (score 29):

Here's what I found so far:

## Title

> The word **listen** in the title looked pretty important from the beginning. It is also repeated in the first line of the question and there is a hint in the crossword (see below).

## Crossword

> The visible hints for horizontal entries give the words ISOLATED, THEOLOGY, PITY, THEORY and KEY. The vertical word EYES was given in the linked image from the question. Filling the remaining letters reveals 2 additional vertical words: TITLE and EIGHTH. The eighth word in the title is **listen**.
>
>  [image]

## Continuation

> I'm stuck for now. The word **listen** suggests that the rest of the puzzle might have to do something with music. The letters A-F could stand for notes (they are obviously not hex numbers as stated in the advertisement). Replacing the numbers below the image with letters from the crossword didn't work for me either (even when using A & D vitamins only).

Comment: As per [this meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4530/etiquette-for-teaming-up-to-solve-a-puzzle), I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36672/this-is-important-i-need-you-to-listen) to discuss theories/work in progress... Feel free to move your notes across there.

Comment: @Alconja Need some sleep now. I'm afraid I won't be able to contribute more until tomorrow.

Answer (score 21):

I'm going to follow another user's example and post an answer to make notes.

**Solving the crossword:**

Thanks to Z. Dailey for the missing words. (1D, 4A, 11D)

> [image: crossword]

Comment: As per [this meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4530/etiquette-for-teaming-up-to-solve-a-puzzle), I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36672/this-is-important-i-need-you-to-listen) to discuss theories/work in progress... Feel free to move your notes across there.

Answer (score 12):

Putting this in an answer so I can properly spoiler it out without doing rot13 in a comment.

Use this for what it is... ideas I've looked into on this... doesn't mean I'm going in the right direction.

> I believe there's a word hidden in the picture and with what ive looked at on it, steganography comes up, so there may be something hidden in the file itself.... also solved the crossword and cant quite gather anything meaningful from the hex like digits below the pic even using letters from those respective words... words 2, 3, and 20 are missing from the page, but the rest of them likely go with the words in the crossword. Vitamins A & D only stands out with the letters used in the hexlike chars tho...

more observations:

> confirmed pic isnt useful in the beginning of the puzzle... i bet the article decodes to instructions for manipulating the picture.
>  2F, 19A, 4E, 11D, 4A, 25C, 11A, 24A, 1B, 3F, 20C --> CF, TA, IE. TD, IA, YC, TA, KA, EB, _F, _C ???? focus on A and D. an anagram basically spits out "at a data kit".

unless someone wants to start a chat on this one and I'll delete this.

Comment: Some good observations... Just to save you some potential wasted time, I'll reiterate that my intuition says that the static image is the last thing you should be looking at. Maybe it will mean more later down the track...

Comment: Yah. I'm not looking at it yet. I read. ;). But some people also say things to be misleading. Either way. Ignoring the pic for now. But it looks like a word goes from bottom left to top right.

Comment: Oh, and there's nothing digitally "hidden" in any of the files themselves, they're just images straight from my camera/scanner. What you see is what you get.

Comment: As per [this meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4530/etiquette-for-teaming-up-to-solve-a-puzzle), I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36672/this-is-important-i-need-you-to-listen) to discuss theories/work in progress... Feel free to move your notes across there.