# Batman and the piano

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story, cipher

> Batman:  `Alfred.  Are you there?`
>   Alfred:  `Yes, Master Bruce.  How may I help you?`
>   Batman:  `I'm still in pursuit of The Riddler, but I've run into a problem.  I've been trapped in a room with a piano, and two paintings on the wall.  One of these paintings is cryptic, even by Nigma's standards.  The other appears to simply be a single measure of sheet music.  The rest of the room is bare.`
>   Alfred:  `What of the piano, Master Bruce?  Have you found any clues there?`
>   Batman:  `I've examined it, thoroughly, but I don't see any way to get inside.  The casing appears to be titanium alloy composite, and I can't find any cracks.  I've scanned the piano, and it's clear that it is somehow connected with the doors to the room.  I fear that hitting random keys, however, will just cause the doors to lock permanently.`
>   Alfred:  `Allow me to see the paintings, then, if you wouldn't mind?`
>   Batman:  `Here.  I'm sending images of them, now.`

---

### Image Received...

[image: Painting 1]

### Image Received...

[image: Painting 2]

---

> Alfred:  `How curious, Master Bruce.  Let me think...`
>   Batman:  `Alfred, Nigma's getting away, and there's a bomb, somewhere in this building!`
>   Alfred:  `Right.  If you wouldn't mind, sir, I know of a group of people to whom I could send this information who would likely be able to assist in solving it.`
>   Batman:  `Go ahead, but make sure they understand..`
>   Alfred:  `We're in a hurry.  Understood, sir.  I'll get back to you.`

---

Alfred:  `You are those people.  Could you please do your best to assist us?  Thank you, ever so much.  I've included the transcript of mine and Master Bruce's conversation, in case it helps, at all.`

Comment: In case anyone's curious, the notes are CEGFADB, all eighth notes.

Comment: Also, that's a *very* high quality camera. Is it [Alconja brand](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28494/this-is-important-i-need-you-to-listen#comment84480_28494)? :P

Comment: He was my other inspiration for this puzzle.  I'll go with yes, to that answer. =D

Comment: ^vote and I'll crack it tomorrow if it's not cracked yet. ;)

Comment: @Deusovi - what's more impressive is that it's allegedly a photo of a *painting*... that's one steady brush hand. :)

Comment: @Alconja Not just that, mixing the paint colors must have taken forever!

Comment: I hate to point out the obvious, but there's no way that Batman can't get into a piano; http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/batman/images/d/d7/Whoswho_ubelt.gif/revision/latest?cb=20110520075224

Comment: Nice try, Robin, but Batman lost his belt during the initial pursuit.

Comment: I think you have my name confused with someone else's...

Comment: Alfred's still waiting on an answer to what notes to press on the piano.  Anyone have an idea?  (I can't approve comments, even if they were correct.)

Comment: I'm fairly certain I know what the song is, just can't recall the what it's called or who played it. If I'm right it's classical

Comment: All music appearing in this work is fictitious. Any resemblance to real music, living or dead, is purely coincidental.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why does he call Batman "Master Bruce"?  The only 'Bruce' I'm aware of is millionaire playboy Bruce Wayne...   I just solved a totally different puzzle!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## The notes to free Master Bruce are:

---

> D C A A F E B

### Explanation

---

The painting can be cleaned up to look like this:

[image: Numbers]
Credit to @2012rcampion

There is also visible morse code repeating around the edge of the original painting that says "VIGINEREX" Credit to @Alconja

The notes on the measure of sheet music are:

```
 CEGFADB
```

Taking the numbers from the cleaned up painting, both @Z.Dailey and @2012rcampion's analysis resulted in a pattern every numbers.

Breaking up the numbers into sets of 7 results in this:

```
 378 207 104   4 108  45 360
  18  99   4  28 156  20 306
 252  36  28  60 204  70 126
 108 189  80   4  24  85 198
  18  63  36   4 312  30 162
 234 189  24  84 216  55  18
 126 144   4 104  72  25  18
 432  72  68  24 240 105  90
  90   9   4 104  72 100 306
 468  81  68  96 288  65 432
 432 207 104   4 108  55  18
 126  36  72  52  72  85 108
 360 153  36  16 252  30 378
 468 171  20   4 312  30 360
 306  81  52  96 288  70 234
 108 225  52 104 168  35 108
 198   9  28  36  12 130 108
 342   9  36  84  72 100  18
 126  54  52  72 252  95 360
 108  54  80  84  60  20  18
  18 225  36   4 312  30 432
 306  54  44   4  84  90  72
 306 153  80   4 108  85 144
 306  36  28 104  72 105 432
 198   9  28  76 204  30 108
 360 153   4  16 192  85  72
 234 234  64   8 288  65 198
 378  54  16  84 228 100 108
  90 153  60   4 312  80 108
 360 153 104  72  12  35  72
 108 180  24  80 204  25 306
  54  63  68 104 180  85 252
 306 171  84 104  60  20 306
  36 153  52  24 252 130 342
 108 180  68  72 252  90 108
 360 126  28  24  12 130 432
 198 198  28  20  72   5 468
 270 153   4 104 204  25 378
 180  36  68  32 204  20  90
 306  54  80  68 312  90 378
 468 117  96  96 132  25 306
 144 153 104  20 240   5 162
 126  45  64  68  72  85 270
 108 189  32  68 132   5 126
 234  36  68 104  72 110 126
  90  54  52  64  84 130 270
 306
```

As listed on the painting the key is "WHO I AM," so taking the values of the characters in "RIDDLER" you get:

```
 18   9   4   4  12   5  18
```

Dividing the numbers down the columns by their key and converting to text you get:
`UWZAIITAKAGMDQNDGOQNGFUTABQKAGIAZFIMUFURKAGPAZFEAXHQFTUEEAAZFTQZIQXXMXXWZAIKAGDRMFQFTQIDUFUZSEAZFTQIMXXNMFYMZNGFKAGIAZFSAIUFTAGFMRUSTFFTUEDAAYIAZFXQFKAGRDQQTAIQHQDGZFUXKAGSQFFTQADPQDMZPBXMKUFDUSTFEQOAZPFTQZRAGDFTFTQEQCGQZOQNQSUZEDQBQMFUZSFTQRURFTNGFAZXKVGEFAZOQAZQEUJDQHQDEQFTQZRUZMXXKEQHQZETAIGEPQFQOFUHQKAGMDQZFVGEFMPGZOQ`

with a shift by 12 (or 90, since the words were turned 90º) a poem is discovered:

```
 I KNOW WHO YOU ARE BRUCE BUT I HOPE YOU WON'T WAIT
 IF YOU DON'T SOLVE THIS SOON THEN WE'LL ALL KNOW YOUR FATE
 THE WRITING'S ON THE WALL BATMAN BUT YOU WON'T GO WITHOUT A FIGHT
 THIS ROOM WON'T LET YOU FREE HOWEVER UNTIL YOU GET THE ORDER AND PLAY IT RIGHT
 SECOND THEN FOURTH THE SEQUENCE BEGINS REPEATING THE FIFTH BUT ONLY JUST ONCE
 ONE SIX REVERSE THEN FINALLY SEVEN SHOW US DETECTIVE YOU AREN'T JUST A DUNCE
```

Credit to @f" and @Varon.

Using the specific instructions along with the notes in the measure (CEGFADB)

```
 SECOND THEN FOURTH THE SEQUENCE BEGINS
 REPEATING THE FIFTH BUT ONLY JUST ONCE
 ONE SIX REVERSE THEN FINALLY SEVEN
```

> The second note is E, the fourth is F
>   The fifth note is A and repeat it once (AA)
>   The first is C the sixth is D
>   This results in EFAACD which needs to be reversed to DCAAFE then add B (seven)

Comment: Calling Alfred...

Comment: Alfred: `I gave the suggested code to Master Bruce.  He informed me that upon pressing these keys, the door with which The Riddler had escaped has just locked.  I'm sure I don't need to inform you that he was upset.  There is only one door remaining: the door that Master Bruce entered from.  We're going to have to find another method to find out where The Riddler has escaped to, but perhaps Master Bruce might just be able to come out of this situation, alive.  I'm sure it doesn't need to be said, but please try to be more sure of your next answer.  I fear we will not get another chance.`

Comment: I don't think it showed you my attempt to edit your post.  "REPEATING" belongs at the beginning of the second line.

Comment: Made an edit, but I'm afraid for you to call Alfred. @BruceWayne might die. :,(

Comment: Happened across this during this puzzle. Fun little tool. http://onlinesequencer.net

Comment: Nice - will keep that in mind! ....It won't allow me to tag you.  It deletes the tag when I try.  @Z.Dailey

Comment: I hope I don't kill Bruce. No one in Gotham would forgive me.

Comment: I gave Alfred all of the information that you all have gathered together and he looked it over.  (Time runs differently in TV land.)  He said that everything seems sound, but he's not sure the notes match the riddle that was given.  He's hesitant to try it, just yet.

Comment: On my answer it automatically tags me in the background.

Comment: By the way, this answer is EXTREMELY close.

Comment: I can't tell if it's supposed to be "one six" or one "six". Haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37345/discussion-between-khale-kitha-and-z-dailey).

Comment: EFAACD (reverse) could mean reverse the whole thing. Reverse the CD. Or just grab the last note played (C). Then B. Hmmmm. How to interpret

Comment: Ok. Now it should be right. XD

Comment: Calling Alfred...

Comment: Did I killed Bruce?

Comment: Alfred: `Thank you.  All of you.  This appears to be the solution to saving Master Bruce.  I will make sure to tell him straig....`  
Riddler: `I FOUND YOU!!  So YOU are the people who were helping the DETECTIVE do his job!  Well I have only you to thank for letting me escape, this time, but next time, even YOU won't be able to save Batman!  Good luck!`

Comment: Yay!  I'll add in all the other parts.

Comment: Good job - go ahead and add those in as soon as you have a chance.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha looks good now :)

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Just wondering, is 'DCAAFEB' standing for *anything* or just an as random solution as it seems? Feels a bit 'surprising' at the end...  Otherwise, very nice puzzle!

Comment: Yeah, it was a random sequence.  I came up with the riddle, and then figured out the sequence, myself, after writing it.  - Sorry for the end.

Answer (score 24):

Starting from the numbers arranged in seven columns as in 2012rcampion's answer, each column contains only numbers divisible by the values of the letters in "riddler":

```
  18   9   4   4  12   5  18
```

Dividing by these numbers leaves only values in the range 1 to 26. Converting to letters leaves: `UWZAIITAKAGMDQNDGOQNGFUTABQKAGIAZFIMUFURKAGPAZFEAXHQFTUEEAAZFTQZIQXXMXXWZAIKAGDRMFQFTQIDUFUZSEAZFTQIMXXNMFYMZNGFKAGIAZFSAIUFTAGFMRUSTFFTUEDAAYIAZFXQFKAGRDQQTAIQHQDGZFUXKAGSQFFTQADPQDMZPBXMKUFDUSTFEQOAZPFTQZRAGDFTFTQEQCGQZOQNQSUZEDQBQMFUZSFTQRURFTNGFAZXKVGEFAZOQAZQEUJDQHQDEQFTQZRUZMXXKEQHQZETAIGEPQFQOFUHQKAGMDQZFVGEFMPGZOQ`

As @Varon pointed out, shifting this forward by 14 results in a poem:

`I KNOW WHO YOU ARE BRUCE BUT I HOPE YOU WON'T WAIT
IF YOU DON'T SOLVE THIS SOON THEN WE'LL ALL KNOW YOUR FATE
THE WRITING'S ON THE WALL BATMAN BUT YOU WON'T GO WITHOUT A FIGHT
THIS ROOM WON'T LET YOU FREE HOWEVER UNTIL YOU GET THE ORDER AND PLAY IT RIGHT
SECOND THEN FOURTH THE SEQUENCE BEGINS REPEATING THE FIFTH BUT ONLY JUST ONCE
ONE SIX REVERSE THEN FINALLY SEVEN SHOW US DETECTIVE YOU AREN'T JUST A DUNCE`

Comment: use `M` as KEY and you get: `IKNOWWHOYOUAREBRUCEBUTIHOPEYOUWONTWAITIFYOUDONTSOLVETHISSOONTHENWELLALLKNOWYOURFATETHEWRITINGSONTHEWALLBATMANBUTYOUWONTGOWITHOUTAFIGHTTHISROOMWONTLETYOUFREEHOWEVERUNTILYOUGETTHEORDERANDPLAYITRIGHTSECONDTHENFOURTHTHESEQUENCEBEGINSREPEATINGTHEFIFTHBUTONLYJUSTONCEONESIXREVERSETHENFINALLYSEVENSHOWUSDETECTIVEYOUARENTJUSTADUNCE`

Comment: @Varon Wait, Bruce Wayne is BATMAN!!!???

Comment: So [according to Deusovi's transcription of the notes](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29278/batman-and-the-piano/29280#comment86647_29278) (CEGFADB), and assuming Ed's poem has the most straightforward meaning (2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7) then the answer should be EFADCB.

Comment: @2012rcampion Clearly you were aware of it.  No one has mentioned `Wayne` anywhere, on the page. =D

Comment: No one has seen Batman and Bruce Wayne in the same room at the same time.... but no one has seen Batman and @2012rcampion in the same room at the same time either....

Comment: That would actually be a shift by 12.  Or...uh...90 ;)

Comment: I may be looking too hard at this but the notes in the sheet music define a C major scale, or in other words the _key of C_.

Answer (score 21):

Engaging detective mode (taking the difference of the red and green channels, although any pair produces the same result), a code is revealed:

[image]

Statistical analysis suggests the numbers come in groups of seven, or there is some kind of repetition or redundancy every seven numbers:

```
 378 207 104   4 108  45 360
  18  99   4  28 156  20 306
 252  36  28  60 204  70 126
 108 189  80   4  24  85 198
  18  63  36   4 312  30 162
 234 189  24  84 216  55  18
 126 144   4 104  72  25  18
 432  72  68  24 240 105  90
  90   9   4 104  72 100 306
 468  81  68  96 288  65 432
 432 207 104   4 108  55  18
 126  36  72  52  72  85 108
 360 153  36  16 252  30 378
 468 171  20   4 312  30 360
 306  81  52  96 288  70 234
 108 225  52 104 168  35 108
 198   9  28  36  12 130 108
 342   9  36  84  72 100  18
 126  54  52  72 252  95 360
 108  54  80  84  60  20  18
  18 225  36   4 312  30 432
 306  54  44   4  84  90  72
 306 153  80   4 108  85 144
 306  36  28 104  72 105 432
 198   9  28  76 204  30 108
 360 153   4  16 192  85  72
 234 234  64   8 288  65 198
 378  54  16  84 228 100 108
  90 153  60   4 312  80 108
 360 153 104  72  12  35  72
 108 180  24  80 204  25 306
  54  63  68 104 180  85 252
 306 171  84 104  60  20 306
  36 153  52  24 252 130 342
 108 180  68  72 252  90 108
 360 126  28  24  12 130 432
 198 198  28  20  72   5 468
 270 153   4 104 204  25 378
 180  36  68  32 204  20  90
 306  54  80  68 312  90 378
 468 117  96  96 132  25 306
 144 153 104  20 240   5 162
 126  45  64  68  72  85 270
 108 189  32  68 132   5 126
 234  36  68 104  72 110 126
  90  54  52  64  84 130 270
 306
```

(Thanks to  Khale_Kitha for correcting some errors in my transcription of the numbers.)

Comment: Nice! My first thought was Magic Eye, but that didn't work. What software did you use for that?

Comment: The numbers may refer to letters or words in the conversation between Bruce and Alfred.

Comment: I'm glad you're awake, @Z.Dailey.  You were my inspiration for this puzzle. :)

Comment: Also, are you sure all 3 give the exact same numbers?

Comment: @Deusovi Mathematica (`ImageAdjust[ImageDifference@@Take[ColorSeparate[Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/VJhI0.png"]],2]]`)

Comment: @Khale_Kitha hehe. I'm glad I came up with one that pushed you to this. :) I got another good one I'm working on now.

Comment: @Deusovi Yes; it looks like the background is gray and the numbers are slightly colored.

Comment: Yah you can halfway read them in the original, just really blurred. @Deusovi

Comment: Ive gotta get up in a few hours and still haven't slept yet. If no one has solved it by tomorrow I'll give it a go or 2.

Comment: @2012rcampion You currently have 2 swapped numbers (not near each other), 1 missing number, and 1 incorrect number, at the time of this writing.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Could you add them in? I doubt the main part of the puzzle is in the transcription, and there's no reason for us to hunt through it when you can fix it easily.

Comment: [Might be relevant.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_I_Am)

Comment: **numbers**: 323  **different numbers**: 72  
**max**: 468, 432, 378, 360, 342, 312, 306, 288 ...  (468 is 4 times included)  
**min**: 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 20 ... , The number of lines are unimportant, because there is just a line break after 36 chars.

Answer (score 13):

*-- Partial answer --*

> 1. The border of the first image contains morse code, which just repeats **VIGENEREX** over and over, so presumably a Vigenère cipher is required at some point (though I'm not sure if the *X* is significant):
>  [image: morse code]
>  2. Presumably the numbers found by 2012rcampion somehow make up the cipher text, but it's unclear how they map to letters. They can't be a straight alphabet substitution as there are 72 unique values:
>  `4 5 8 9 12 16 18 20 24 25 28 30 32 35 36 44 45 52 54 55 60 63 64 65 68 70 72 76 80 81 84 85 90 95 96 99 100 104 105 108 110 117 126 130 132 144 153 156 162 168 171 180 189 192 198 204 207 216 225 228 234 240 252 270 288 306 312 342 360 378 432 468`
>  3. The title of the first image (*Who I Am*) has pictures of keys along with the words, so I'm guessing the key to the vigenere is "THERIDDLER" or "NIGMA" or "EDWARD" or something similar...

Comment: Maybe the last letter is the key?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI - it did cross my mind, and is entirely possible, but it would be pretty odd to have a single character key for a vigenere cipher.

Comment: "WHO I AM" has keys around it... maybe that's the key?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI: Alternatively the notes are the key...

Comment: X is commonly used as a space or separator in cryptography, so it may just signify a break.

Comment: I've run the transcript text through forward and backwards pulling the characters associated with the numbers in the pic.  Time to make an attempt at cracking the vigenere.

Comment: Looking at f'''s answer, it seems I was probably wrong: the `X` probably refers to multiplication of the plaintext by the key (which *was* `RIDDLER`)