# Ohh, NSA Again?

Tags: cipher, story

So I decided to write this puzzle with a story, something like [that](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30309/my-puzzling-girlfriend), hope you like it. Happy puzzling! Here is a story:

---

The undercover agent John had infiltrated a terrorist cell. They were planning something bad, a hack or something. They passed messages to each other hand by hand, encrypted, of course.

As John overheard, they are going to hack the next day. The NSA needs to know what the target is.

So, that night, John captured 1 conspirator. He didn't say anything new, but he had a note:

> Target is: $7/\<|<

Seems like it was a "bull's-eye".

**What's the target?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a very ciphery cipher, but

> the "target" looks to me like 1337-speak for STACK

in which case

> perhaps the (rather unlikely) target is **Stack Exchange** or **Stack Overflow**.

Comment: Rather unlikely? [Or maybe not ...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=serial+user%3A2518)

Comment: I'ts correct answer! Target was Stack Overflow!!!