# Ohh, NSA Again? #2

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, story

This puzzle is the second part of story [Ohh, NSA again?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105998/ohh-nsa-again). Hope like this story. Here it is:

---

John got the **target**, it was *Stack*. Problem is, it can be *Stack Overflow* or *Stack Exchange*.

Another problem is that it doesn't concern NSA. Anyway, next day no attacks were detected on *Stack Overflow* or *Stack Exchange*.

Well, after that, John discovered that something strange was happening with NSA system. 
This puzzle had multiple variants to solve.

Is the NSA being hacked? If so, how? And why *Stack Overflow* wasn't attacked?

> NSA technicians used flash drives to scan *Stack Overflow*'s servers. On their flash drives they had many tools that were very helpful at scanning. There were also newby's in that team.

> Guys in that terrorist cell were joking about how strong the software is *they(when they talked about target)* used.

> After some time John recaptured the terrorist and terrorist's phone was blocked. NSA technicians are trying to decrypt phone data.

Comment: Is the wording part of the puzzle? (*"John recaptured terrorist..."* rather than *"John recaptured the terrorist"*)

Comment: @LioElbammalf there is no steganography tag, so no.

Comment: 'No attacks were detected'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess:

> Stack Overflow people are the terrorists or are at least convening with them. When the inexperienced people were scanning overflow's servers some of their passwords got leaked that were contained in those flash drives, the stack overflow team somehow were able to hack them in the process.

> The orginal terrorist ploy was a scam organised to make NSA think that Stack Overflow were under attack and that was why the phone data was easier to decrypt before hand as opposed to this time: they wanted the NSA to dycrpt the phone information last time so they will scan Stack Overflow's servers.

Comment: That's very interesting answer!