# This is an opportunity. Can you take it?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, imgur-maze

The first thing you hear on awakening is the clock. It sounds just like the one you have in your room. But what you see defies what you hear.

You've never seen this room before. You don't remember how you got here. The last thing you can remember is that your mission went horribly wrong...

Wincing, you get up and survey the scene in front of you. As you reach up, and feel a painfully large lump on the back of your head, a [crumpled piece of paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIwn0.jpg) falls out your top. You tuck into your pocket, thinking it will be important later. You look at the door and don't need to go over there to know that it's locked. Here's the room you see (click for a better view)

[image: Room]

> **Can you escape?**

This will be important later:

> **QNW**

**NOTE:**

> I created all the images from scratch though I occasionally used an online image in the making of my images which I don't claim as my own. If you find something odd in an image which doesn't appear to be a clue, it's probably an unintentional error which (probably) won't affect the puzzle.

Comment: [Hint](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28494/this-is-important-i-need-you-to-listen#comment84345_28494) ;)

Comment: Are the cryptic clues standard fare? That is, do they each have a definition half and a wordplay half?

Comment: @Deusovi, I'm not sure if that tag really applies. I think I'll remove it and just keep the cryptic crossword

Comment: I appreciate the concept and the effort put into this puzzle, but I think there are too many clues that require an intuitive leap.  I think it would be very difficult to follow the train of thought spelled out as the intended answer.  The puzzle was only solved by brute-forcing the ciphers, because the clues to the cipher keys were too subtle and/or indirect.  This is not intended to discourage, but only to provide some feedback for future puzzles.  Congratulations on an interesting and intriguing puzzle!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: The cryptic-crossword tag is *also* for actual cryptic crosswords. I recommend reading up on them - your crossword isn't "cryptic" at all, unfortunately.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, thanks for the feedback, I'll take that into future puzzles

Comment: @Mithrandir, you insert an image then instead of it saying [1][1] after you say 1 2 and provide a link at the bottom, click edit and see

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solution:

> On the enlarged picture, there is an open book on the shelf with something that looks like an [imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yRkA.gif).
>  I made a screenshot about that gif, and typed the letters, so here they are for copy-paste:
>
> ```
> fkx wpwax iggqkl mg zighva gsfhhixxdu
> pshc wvsnfz erw ldmrd scemg'qky jhmjh whea jshv plsnyd
> 5gugo.lrk
> fol'zf zvcbme wu tyqt fvod qu kplc jmcd ug apcu
> i'd i ecbbcm bulnk
> q'ws sewb zcb cccfg ao vadowe
> wqor
> ahv xbgz cflf hv lzdf
> tpnu bjal ow mydsojqpb
> zo pwv yuon ppk tutp
> uwte pwv vhvv tfta
> ```
>
> I tried decoding this as a Vigenere cipher with the key given in the hint ('QNW'), but it fails. Maybe that comes to use in a later step.
>
>  @Strawberry suggested using 'sweet' as a key. (I suppose it comes from the [crossword to which there was another link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucBTN.jpg) on the table on the enlarged image).
>  That one gives:
>
> ```
> not sweet enough to decode completely
> look around and think again'you found some food though
> 5cqnw.png
> mwp'vb gdgxil ey puxb jrkk yy glsk niyk ck wljc
> m'z e lkfxyt jyhjr
> y'ao olef vyi kgybn is rwkwaa
> sxwv
> wdc ffcv jnpb dc tdzb
> axrq xqip ks tghokqytx
> vv xar ubwr llr bypl
> bexa ldd zdrc bjpw
> ```
>
> The second key for the second half of the message is 'haribo'. That must be sweet enough indeed. I kind of bruteforced it, supposing the message starts with either 'you've' or 'you're'. It reads:
>
> ```
> you're locked in this room it will blow up soon
> i'm a double agent
> i've left you clues to escape
> find
> the pass code to live
> find time of explosion
> so you know how much
> time you have left
> ```
>
> Maybe the time of explosion is 10:30 as written on the calendar. So we've around 20 minutes left. We have to hurry, but also, need to think with a calm head. What might the pass code be?
>
>  Ok, so in the first decoded version of the message, '5cqnw.png' suggests imgur again. Changing 'qnw' into 'QNW', we get a [valid imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cQNW.png) - thanks for the observation, @Ankoganit. The new image contains a carton of a cereal titled "N**E**W S**W**EEN**E**E**S**" which seems to be compass-directions.
>  As the crumpled piece of paper had a compass on it, this should probably used on that.
>  Starting from the specially marked box, we get:
>  II, **III**, II, V, **IV**, V, IV, III, **I**, IV, **III**,
>  which are all roman numerals, the ones for which the directions were underlined read **3413**.

---

***EDIT FROM OP***

> This answer is almost completely correct, but I'd just like to add a few things that were missed out, or not clearly stated.
>
> First of all in the first room, the newspaper headline says **Another Bomb Murder**. This is another clue that the room will explode. 
>
> When the image is clicked on new things appear. The newspaper changes to a Crossword with **ucBTN.jpg** written. Changing the end of the imgur link gives us:
> [image: Crossword]
> The first clue is 'grain turned sugary'. Grarin is wheat. Wheat turned sugary is **sweet**
> The second clue is 'A 3rd exists'. To be is to exist. **Is** is 3rd person of be.
> The third clue is 'Grants power of entrance', which is a **key**
> The last clue is 'Common determiner'. **The**
> Rearranged this gives us **Sweet is the key**
> The other thing that changes is that the book on the shelf changes to give **2yRkA.gif**. Changing the link gives us a GIF of a book. A page flips over to give the text that  @elias kindly wrote out.
> Using 'sweet' as the key gives 
> 'Not sweet enough to decode completely, look around and think again. You found some food though. 5cqnw.png.
> So sweet isn't the key. But in the far left cupboard in the enlarged image is this: 
> [image: haribo packet]
> It's hard to make out in the shadow of the cupboard but you can just make out the 'H' in Haribo. So 'Haribo' is the sweet that is the key.
> Using Haribo to decode the cipher you learn that you're locked in the room which will explode, but a double agent has left clues to escape.
> Changing the imgur adress to 5cqnw.png gives nothing but by using QNW, we get a new room. This has a cereal packet:
> [image: cereal]
> This has another clue that the room is going to explode with the explosion around new. So 'New Explosion'. The name of the cereal is **NEW SWEENEES**.
> Interestingly =this only contains the letters NSEW which are all part of the compass. Under the packet is says **'Cereal that directs you'**.
> This tells us to use the NEWSWEENEES as directions. On the map which fell out or top.
> There are four letters underlined in the cereal packet, the second, fifth, ninth and eleventh.
> On the map those underlined letters give us **3413**
> On the table is an envelope this is an unsubtle clue to the postbox in the door. In the enlarged version we get this:
> [image: door]
> By typing in 3413 you escape! The explosion happens twenty minutes later (the calendar) after the area has been evacuated after you tell the police.

Comment: As almost all clues are used (I think), the numbers on the paper might as well be the (final?) code for the door.

Comment: I think we will still see the message in the envelop at a point. And there is also something in the cupboard on the left. I wouldn't say we are close to an end yet.

Comment: Ye... probably. Just trying to get the easy way out ;) Good work so far!

Comment: The time on the calendar has changed in colour between the two images.

Comment: @JonathanAllan The hand of the clock as well. I guess it's just quality change in image compression. One of the things OP had a remark about in the last paragraph.

Comment: Ah, yes. Seems odd that the message talks about finding the time of the explosion.

Comment: Why are EWES underlined? That must be significant.

Comment: @elias well done! You've almost completed the puzzle already! Do you mind if I add an edit adding in the tiny things you've missed but don't affect the puzzle?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, please feel free to do so. Every improvement is welcome!

Comment: @elias okay added a probably too long edit. Please feel free to add some of it to your answer. That way yours becomes complete and mine becomes shorter :) You can use the pictures as well if you want

Comment: So it turns out @Christoph was right, we don't have to use the envelope, and that was already the final code. It's a cool puzzle, thanks, @BeastlyGerbil!

Comment: @elias, the envelope was something of a red herring, it just pointed to the postbox so wasn't really a clue. You have indeed solved this puzzle!