# Who stole the diamond?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, imgur-maze

<sub>Inspiration from [@BeastlyGerbil's Puzzle - This is an opprtunity. Can you take it?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41150/this-is-an-opportunity-can-you-take-it)</sub>

---

In Puzzlville last night, someone stole the famous Stone of Wondrous Mystery! 
Can **you** help the police find it? But first... maybe you should read the news.

[image]

<sub>Note: I cannot confirm that all of the images came through clearly enough. If you find that there's something that you can't... read, then let me know, and I can supply the original image that you can't read... probably.</sub>

### Hint:

> There's a *reason* that there's one dark green and one light green in each sudoku box. Also, I made a mistake - *foe* should be *for*.

Comment: I advise you to click on the picture...

Comment: Barcode on the cereal: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dB3ow.png

Comment: Cells. Dark, then light. Newspaper.

Comment: @randal'thor But pretend it is - do NOT pretend that that 'n' is there.

Comment: @Mithrandir Ditto for "commitee" with one T?

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah.

Comment: Whoever crafted this image needs to brush up on their OCD skills

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Final Complete Answer:

---

The original image QR gives:

> Charles = Kyle

Clicking on the image and reading the QR there gives

> vavqvny=qrnz (@Deusovi points out this is rot13 for initial=team)

Notably it's upside down

[The barcode on the cereal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB3ow.png)  says:

> cereal

And the QR says:

> irving=corey

The barcode on the side gives

> E5vEw.png

a link to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5vEw.png)

The QR there says:

> casper is actually jon. jon skeet. heh heh heh. just kidding. but he's really jon.

The barcode there says:

> bart=j.a.

there is also a hidden imgur address

> 'aayEK.png'

which leads to:

> [image: picture]

The solution to the sudoku is:

> [image: finished]

The light green tiles give:

> 418862151

The dark green tiles give:

> 131399235

The suspects as listed below give their stories:

> <strike>Charles</strike> Kyle Hendricks (26) [Chicago Cubs Pitcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyle_Hendricks) - Last night, I was out late at the Sphinx's bar, drinking with my buddies. Then at 'round midnight, I staggered off home, you know, at 28 Enigma Road. You can check with my buddies if you want.
> <strike>Wesley Roak</strike> Tanner Roark (34) [Washington Nationals Pitcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanner_Roark) - I was just too tired to go to the game, I was sleeping. I haven't been anywhere near that museum. It's full of boring strange things - why would I go there?
> <strike>Casper Lester</strike> Jon Lester (29) [Chicago Cubs Pitcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Lester) - I was out of town last night, visiting my pop in Yhpargonagets [Steganography backwards]. I didn't touch no diamond.
> <strike>Irving Kluber</strike> Corey Kluber (31) [Cleveland Indians Pitcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corey_Kluber) - could not be found
> <strike>Bartholomew J. Happ</strike> James Anthony Happ (37) [Toronto Blue Jays Pitcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._A._Happ) - could not be found

@Mithrandir has said Dark green then Light green so

> 131399235418862151

there is also another imgur link

> [image]

leading to:

> [image]

That has a link

> [image]

to

> [image]
> The bear from sesame street

From this @Scimonster correctly deduced

> That the baseball pitch and a baby bear indicates the **[CUBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Cubs)**
> So the culprit is either Kyle Hendricks or Jon Lester

It has been repeatedly said Dark the Light so:

> You will notice that each cell in the Sudoku has 1 dark green and 1 light green. The dark green number indicates the line number in the newspaper, the light green represents the letter. I'll edit in each line in a second. (Thanks @Scimonster)

Using this we get

> 1. Dark = 1 Light = 4 - Las**t** night, under cover of
> 2. Dark = 1 Light = 8 - Last nig**h**t, under cover of
> 3. Dark = 3 Light = 1 - **b**roke into the Museum - Mistake
> 4. Dark = 9 Light = 6 - Myste**r**y. Upon arriving
> 5. Dark = 3 Light = 8 - broke in**t**o the Museum
> 6. Dark = 9 Light = 2 - M**y**stery. Upon arriving
> 7. Dark = 5 Light = 1 - **f**ounded by the Commitee 
> 8. Dark = 2 Light = 1 - o**f** darkness, someone
> 9. Dark = 3 Light = 5 - brok**e** into the Museum - Mistake
>
> **thbrtyfoe**

However @Mithrandir says in the hint that 'foe' should be 'four'. There also seems to be another error. It should actually be

> Thirty Fo(u)r

Which is

> [Jon Lester's Shirt Number](https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-1nrqf/products/4136/images/55904/jon_lester_chicago_cubs_shirt__35601.1457232340.1280.1280.jpg?c=2)

So the thief is

> <strike>Jon Skeet</strike> [**Jon Lester**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Lester)

Comment: Just a note, you've probably noticed, Yhpargonagets is Steganography backwards.

Comment: @Zikato ...And the field is Cipher Field, and the teams are Riddlers and Mathers, and the town is Puzzlville... :P

Answer (score 8):

**Partial Answer**

In the first image, there's a barely-visible

> 5-character code on the right that links to:
>  [image]
>  That has another code (jddiw) linking to a very similar image, but with a picture of Baby Bear from Sesame Street.

The QR code says

> `Charles = kyle.`

There's another similar code if you

> click the image. It's a barcode that says "E5vEw.png", which is an image:
>  [image]

And also

> a rot13ed, upside down message in a QR code that says "initial = team".

More codes to scan:

> The cereal box QR code says "irving = corey".
>  The cereal box barcode says "cereal". (Thanks, very helpful. :P )
>  The bottom right barcode says "bart = j.a."
>  The middle QR code says "casper is actually jon. jon skeet. heh heh heh. just kidding. but he's really jon."

There is another 5-character code

> on the cereal bowl, wich links to an image:
>  [image]
>  The barcode once again just says "cereal".

That sudoku's solution:

> `734 251 689`
>  `628 479 513`
>  `951 683 724`
>
>  `172 836 945`
>  `469 527 831`
>  `583 914 276`
>
>  `896 142 357`
>  `247 365 198`
>  `315 798 462`

The light green squares are:

> 4, 1, 8, 8, 6, 2, 1, 9, 1.

The dark green squares are:

> 1, 3, 1, 3, 9, 9, 2, 3, 5.

Not sure what to do with those - A1Z26 doesn't seem to produce anything useful.

So the *real* suspects are:

> Kyle Hendricks, age 26 (pitcher for the Chicago Cubs)
>  Wesley Roark, age 34 (Tanner Roark: pitcher for Washington Nationals)
>  Jon Lester, age 29 (pitcher for the Chicago Cubs)
>  Corey Kluber, age 31 (pitcher for the Cleveland Indians)
>  Bartholomew J. Happ, age 37 (James Anthony Happ: pitcher for the Toronto Blue Jays)

Comment: Charles Hendricks apparently lives at 28 Enigma Rd. The real Kyle Hendricks wears uniform #28. Coincidence? I think not.

Comment: @Scimonster I think that is just an easter egg

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer: (Including final solution)

> The two TV screens that get linked at some point show a baseball field and Baby Bear. The logical conclusion is that we're dealing with the Cubs.

We can then narrow down [Deusovi's list](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42009/4456) to two suspects:

> Kyle (aka Charles) Hendricks, age 26 (pitcher for the Chicago Cubs)
>  Jon (aka Casper) Lester, age 29 (pitcher for the Chicago Cubs)

As for which one, it has to have something to do with

> the numbers from the sudoku puzzle

<s>But i cannot figure out what.</s>

> Dark then light. They come in pairs. The first number of the pair is the line number; the second is the letter number.

If we use this on the news article in the first image, this gives us:

> thbrtyfoe

From the hint we know

> Also, I made a mistake - foe should be for.

And there appears to be another error, so in the end we get

> thirtyfo[u]r

Which is

> [Jon Lester's uniform number](http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/l/lestejo01.shtml).

So the culprit is:

> Jon (aka Casper) Lester, #34, age 29 (pitcher for the Chicago Cubs)