# The mysterious email on Mithrandir's Puzzlers Mail

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, imgur-maze

<sub>Original inspiration from [@BeastlyGerbil's puzzle - *This is an opportunity. Can you take it?*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41150/25966)</sub>

---

I have just received this email, from someone who Puzzlers Email couldn't give me any info on - it just says 'Unknown'. I took a picture with my camera - maybe you can figure out what on earth this guy is saying, because I'm lost.

[image: the email itself]

### Hint

> Short people have more than you realize...

Comment: Wow by the look of the boot case this will take a long time to solve

Comment: The snake made me to consider upvoting.

Comment: Given the title, I suspect you got inspiration from somewhere else as well as Beastly's puzzle ;-)

Comment: I happen to see Rand Al'thor's pic on the image....

Comment: I don't have enough to even make a partial answer, but there's a 'B' and an 'LKGRY.GIF' hidden in the image. Entering that into imgur urls (in various forms of capitalization) has come up empty.

Comment: @TimC Yes, that's a valid link - the capitalization is in there. Ignore the B - it's a leftover. o_o

Comment: @Mithrandir Aha. Got it.

Comment: @Mithrandir bounty ends in 5 hours...

Comment: 1 hour now.....

Comment: 1 minute.......

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The person who emailed you is trying to tell you

> Harry Potter and the Cursed Child is bad.

Your mind wanders back to the effort they put into hiding this message...

---

Clicking on the image you found a picture of a bookcase and a computer. The bookcase contained links which led to other images. A lot were filler images, but there were a few that caught your eye...

> Some of the images seemed to contain hidden text. [The life of Fred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXkZe.png) had Q3 and h2 quite obviously in it. [Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcYeX.png) contained Y1.

The trickiest to find

> Was in [The Hobbit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GndgI.png). It is very hard to see but there is a [q5 in the top right above the brim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glY5a.png) and a [p4 in the top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnZVt.png). You had to zoom in a lot.

Ordering them from their numbers gave

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhQpq.png gives us

which is

> [image].

The numbers seeemed to correspond with

> The numbers in the email. To decode you must take the number in the email, find its match and replace it with the letters

By decoding the entire email with this you got

> Hello, Mithrandir. Once you and your little friends have decoded this, go to UOSvt.png. I will wait and watch.

So you went to

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOSvt.png

And found

> [image]

To solve it you had to go back to the bookcase and to the book labelled [Saruman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inZEz.png). In it you found

> A hidden imgur link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7xgk.png

Which gave you

> [image]

The small text at the bottom was

> Bayl jbeqf gung ner 3 yrggref ybat - ROT13 for
> 'Only words that are 3 letters long'

So you solved the crossword with words 3 letters or longer and were found only a few letters remained unused.

> [image: (I'll add a solved crossword later)]

The letters left over were:

> ldhdcdbuerac

You also had to add an 'i' from the hidden link in the 'divergent' link:

> [image]

And an 's' from the [Gas Gage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2AVA.png).:

> [image]

So the final letters were:

> ldhdicdbsuerac

Which descrambled to:

> Cursed Child: Bad.

You sccessfully unlocked the email's secrets.

Comment: @Mithrandir you mean wrong track for the 3 letter words bit?

Comment: If I remember correctly Monster Donut is a reference to one of the books in the Percy Jackson series 1.

Comment: I dont understand. Where are q5 and p4?

Comment: @bleh *very* hard to see

Comment: Q5 i can sort of see. p4 is just indistinguishable

Comment: I could only see q5 and p4 after using Equalize in Gimp on these images.

Comment: @MariaDeleva I had to squint a lot just looking at the images. Eyesight of Youth

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil or perhaps it is my monitor... :) I don't think I am that old yet... :P

Comment: @Mithrandir when I solve the puzzle I'll focus on making the images and answer 1) well ordered 2) correct

Comment: At this point it's farily obvious that the persom sending it is Rand'al Thor

Comment: @Mithrandir, that would work... Tell me when you've added it.

Answer (score 6):

<sub>**Note:** I didn't try to click on the image yet when I wrote this answer, so the following is *extremely* partial and [could be superfluous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45875/the-mysterious-email-on-mithrandirs-puzzlers-mail#comment138655_45877).</sub>

---

**Partial answer**

When

> ```
> 427 = H
> 826 = E
> 26 = L
> 703 = O
> 504 = M
> 524 = I
> 534 = T
> 629 = R
> 698 = A
> 946 = N
> 857 = D
> 524 = I
> 385 = C
> 112 = T
> 840 = F
> 165 = S
> 9 = Y
> 256 = U
> 555 = V
> 825 = E
> 280 = W
> ```

Then the message partially decodes to

> ```
> HELLO, MITHRANDIR. ONCE YOU AND YOUR LITTLE FRIENDS HAVE DECODED THIS, TO 634 O TIYNT 315 YLT. I WILL WAIT AND WAICH...
> ```
>
> ---
>
> I think the `524` in the last line is supposed to be a `534`. Not sure why `TO 634 O TIYNT 315 YLT` is so much nonsense for some reason... I also still have to figure out what `634` and `315` decodes to.

If the mapping so far is correct, the numbers with a blue border decode to:

> HMOINTI

Comment: The answers are in there. You're supposed to *find* the answers, not actually *solve* it! :)

Comment: @Mithrandir Um... Wow, can't believe I didn't click on  the image yet... Thanks.

Comment: Just BTW: I updated the image, so you may want to update this. And, a clarification: The *key* is in the puzzle, not the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a lead on for other people to come.

This pic

> [image: layman]

corresponds to the

> Pippen cipher probably.

But the text is nonsense, but there is a clear structure

> njwj jwtr jrtx jpnq in wnx jxfju

Just too long for a comment

Also, the Magnus chase one

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry0kK.jpg] is Samariah al-Abbas. A Valkerie.

Don quixote.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TnmF.jpg] can be nothing less than Rand al'Thor's donkey on SFF.SE, because he has not watched a single Star Wars movie.

I have no clue what a gas gage is, but

> a sphygmomanometer apparently is what it is. [image: sphbleh]